# PDF Encryption from Kofax Capture Text Export Connector

Tags: encryption, export, connector, kofax

I am trying to encrypt pdf files that will be exported after processed by kofax capture.
Going through the documentation I found this code:

Add the following tag in ACConfig.xml to prevent the PDF Generator from producing encrypted PDF files
with blank passwords. (635584, tag introduced in Kofax Capture 10.2.0.3)

```
 <PDFExport Encryption="1" Password="kofax">
 <Profile Name="abc" Encryption="0"/>
 <Profile Name="def" Encryption="1" Password="kofax123"/>
 </PDFExport>
```

For the "abc" profile, the encryption will be turned off.
For the "def" profile, the encryption will be turned on with the password of kofax123.
For other profiles, the encryption will be turned on with the password of kofax.
Note The values defined for the Encryption and Password attributes in the PDFExport tag are applied
to all profiles except the ones overridden by the Profile tag. Also, the default values of the Encryption
and Password attributes are "0" and empty.

Not sure if the code should be on the releaseScript or the acconfig file. I would greatly appreciate your help in directing me the right direction to customize the text export connector. I am using Capture 10.2

Answer (score 1):

The xml snippet you reference should be added to the ACConfig.xml file.  For clarity below is the full text of the mention of this feature in the 10.2.0.3 release notes (part of which is in your question).  You can see that the PDFExport tag is added within the ACConfig tag, which is the top-level tag in ACConfig.xml.

```
635584 - Creating a PDF with version 1.6/1.7 generates a protected file
 with a blank password.
 Add the tag <PDFExport> to ACConfig.xml: 
 Example:
 <ACConfig>
    ...
    <PDFExport Encryption="1" Password="kofax" >
        <Profile Name="abc" Encryption="0" />
        <Profile Name="def" Encryption="1" Password="kofax123" />
    </PDFExport>
    ...
 </ACConfig>
 For the "abc" profile, the encryption will be turned off.
 For the "def" profile, the encryption will be turned on with the password of "kofax123".
 For other profiles, the encryption will be turned on with the password of "kofax".

 Note: 
 - The values defined for the Encryption and Password attributes in PDFExport tag will be 
       applied to all profiles except the ones overriden by the Profile tag.
 - The default value of Encryption and Password attributes are "0" and empty.
```